# How do i trigger a form submit after validating with <apex:actionFunction>?

Tags: rerender, actionfunction, ajax

I have a form that i need to validate 1 field by the controller,

**what is the right way to to preform validation with the controller and by the answer to preform form submission??**

Heres the **VFP code**:

```
<apex:outPutPanel id="script_block">
    <script>
        var submitDisabled = '{!submitDisabled}';
        function performValidation(){
            // 1. check with controller preSubmitCase method
            // 2. if "submitDisabled" callback is true then submit the form, if not then raise an error to the user
        }
    </script>
</apex:outPutPanel>

<apex:form id="myform" >

    <apex:input   id="acctReporting_on" value="{!acctReporting_on}"/> //Required field
    <input type="button"  onclick="performValidation();" value="Submit" />
    <apex:actionFunction name="preSubmitCase" action="{!preSubmitCase}" reRender="form" />
    <apex:commandButton value="Submit Case"   action="{!submitCase}"/>

</apex:form>
```

And here's the **controller code**:

```
public class SubmitCaseController {

    public Boolean submitDisabled {get; set;}
    public String acctReporting_on { get; set; }

     public PageReference preSubmitCase() {

        submitDisabled = false; 
        List<Account> accts = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :acctReporting_on];
        if(accts.size() == 1) {
            submitDisabled = true;
        }
        return null;
     }

    public PageReference submitCase() {
        //form submition function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your code as follows, added `rerender` to your form and `disabled` to command button:

Page:

```
<apex:form id="myform" >
    <apex:input id="acctReporting_on"
        value="{!acctReporting_on}"/>

    <!-- call action function directly from onclick -->
    <input type="button" 
        value="Submit"
        onclick="performValidation();"/>

    <!-- call controller method for validation -->
    <apex:actionFunction name="performValidation"
            action="{!preSubmitCase}"
            reRender="myform"/>

    <!-- added disabled tag to conditionally -->
    <apex:commandButton value="Submit Case"
        action="{!submitCase}" 
        disabled="{!submitDisabled}"/>
</apex:form>
```

Class:

```
public class SubmitCaseController {

    public Boolean submitDisabled { get; set; }
    public String acctReporting_on { get; set; }

    public SubmitCaseController() {
        // on load disable submit
        submitDisabled = false;
    }

     public void preSubmitCase() {
        List<Account> accts = [SELECT Id FROM Account 
            WHERE Name = :acctReporting_on];
        // if there are records, this would be true
        submitDisabled = accts.size() == 1;
     }

    public PageReference submitCase() {
        //form submition function
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do i write inside my performValidation() funciotn?

Comment: Sorry, you do not need action function as well, validation can be done in submitCase function itself. will update answer.

Comment: Updated my answer, you would need to add rerender to your form and add disabled to command button. I misread HTML `input` as `apex:input`, really need a coffee!

Comment: Ok, Greate, i'v implemented it with keypress event on the "acctReporting_on" , input and rerendered only the submit button  and its working fine!